# how to remove a part of a url from a url using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript variable

```
var url =  http://www.abc.it/it/security/security.aspx?security=pdfcompare&../securitycomparepdf/default.aspx?SecurityTokenList=blab]2]0]blab$ALL|blab]2]0]blab$ALL|blab]2]0]blab$ALL;
```

I need to remove the part `"../securitycomparepdf/default.aspx?"` from it using jquery, so that the variable becomes

```
http://www.abc.it/it/security/security.aspx?security=pdfcompare&SecurityTokenList=blab]2]0]blab$ALL|blab]2]0]blab$ALL|blab]2]0]blab$ALL;
```

Can someone please suggest?

Thanks

Comment: jQuery does not provide string manipulation methods, you have to use methods provided by JavaScript itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made a demo for you: http://jsfiddle.net/B3Uwj/27/ (from @tats_innit)

```
url = url.replace("../securitycomparepdf/default.aspx?", "");
```

Comment: @ronanmarsh: Then you might have another problem somewhere and you should provide more information about your situation. We can only work with what you give us. If your code is like you posted, I can tell you that it is not valid JavaScript, the URL must be contained in string delimiters. The more information you provide, the better answers you will get.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following JS

```
var url = "http://www.abc.it/it/security/security.aspx?security=pdfcompare&../securitycomparepdf/default.aspx?SecurityTokenList=blab]2]0]blab$ALL|blab]2]0]blab$ALL|blab]2]0]blab$ALL";

url = url.replace("../securitycomparepdf/default.aspx?","");

​alert(url);​
```

See a live example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wCGDj/)